# How to store lists in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

What is the  best way to store lists in postgresql?
What kind of field do I have to use? do I have to serialize it?

This is an example of data that I want to store:

id ( number ), name ( text ), events ( list )

```
1, john connor, ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]

2, jack bush, ["ttt","hhh","lll"]

...
```

Comment: You don't. You create another table and link to the main though a foreign key. A pretty standard parent-child DB relationship.

Comment: @Alejandro Can't I even serialize the list and store it in the column?

Comment: You could, but it violates the best practices for [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @xRobot You certainly can, you can save a string that contains anything, but doing so will lead to **many** problems down the road. Use another table and save the hassle.

Comment: @xRobot All RDBMS are based on the concept on data `Normalization` (google it - you will find a lot). The first step is called 1st Normal Form (1NF) and part of that is removing all repeating groups. An array or list of any kind violates that. It only leads to maintenance and data issues down the line.  As mentioned pull your list out into another table with a column for values. You can always rebuild the list or array with a query but avoid the data abnormalities you will get with a list or array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)? They are declared with `[]` for any size and `[3]` for array with 3 cells.

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id integer,
  name text,
  events text[]);
  
INSERT into test1 (id, name, events)
    values(1, 'john connor', '{"aaa", "bbb","ccc"}'),
          (2, 'jack bush', '{"ttt", "hhh","lll"}');
```

When inputting arrays, everything has to be enclosed in curly braces AND the curly braces have to be enclosed in single quotes. Finally, strings inside arrays must use double quotes.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
id  name            events
1   john connor     {aaa,bbb,ccc}
2   jack bush       {ttt,hhh,lll}
```

Comment: Great, are there some limit on using arrays in postgresql?

Comment: @xrobot, I haven't come across any huge drawbacks for arrays. When you go to retrieve data, you will be limited in the ways you can rearrange the data with [array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-array.html).

Answer (score -2):

Use json
example

```
select
    json_build_object(
        user_id,
        json_build_object(
            'user_name',
            table.user_name
            'aaa',
            table.aaa,
            'bbb',
            table.bbb,
            'ccc',
            table.ccc
        )
 )
from table
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.